# Save the contents of JTextArea embedded in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

As the question states, I'm trying to save the contents of JTextArea which I've embedded into a JTabbedPane. I know how to save the contents of a JTextArea, but I can't figure out how to save its contents when it's embedded in a JTabbedPane.

The problem is that I'm adding the tab dynamically, like it's done in Gedit. I don't know how to save the newly generated tab.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

class tabbed

{

 public static void main(String[] arhs)

 {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("");

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



  final JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();



  JButton butadd   = new JButton("Add");

  JButton butcheck = new JButton("Save");



  JPanel north = new JPanel();

  JPanel south = new JPanel();



  north.add(butadd);

  south.add(butcheck);



  ActionListener listenadd = new ActionListener()

  {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

   {

    tab.add("Untitled",new JTextArea());

   }

  };

  butadd.addActionListener(listenadd);

  frame.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  frame.add(tab);

  frame.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  frame.setSize(450,450);

  frame.setVisible(true);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your problem down into individual steps:

1. Get the currently selected tab
2. Get the text are displayed on that tab
3. Save the contents of the text area using the write(...) method of the text area